# First order difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the problem : "An investor deposits 1000$\$$ in an account paying interest at a rate of 7 %, compounded monthly, and also makes additional deposits of 25$\$$ per month. Find the balance in the account after 4 years" using a difference equation.

Answer (score 0):

First set up the problem, defining $x_0 = 1000$, and $x_{n+1} = (1.07)x_{n} + 25$. Since $n$ refers to the number of months, and we're looking to pass $4$ years, we're looking to compute $x_{48}$.

Let's examine some of the initial terms. Notice $$x_1 = 1.07x_0 + 25 = (1.07)(1000) + 25.$$ Also, $$x_2 = (1.07)x_1 + 25 = (1.07)[(1.07)(1000) + 25] + 25 = (1.07)^2(1000) + (1.07)25 + 25.$$ It seems to be that we have $$x_n = (1.07)^n(1000) + 25 + 25(1.07) + \dots + 25(1.07)^{n-1}$$.

Remember that $$a + ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{n-1} = \dfrac{a\left(1 - r^n\right)}{1 - r}.$$

So setting $a = 25, r = 1.07$ in the above expression, we get $$x_n = 1.07^n(1000) + \dfrac{25\left(1 - 1.07^n\right)}{1 - 1.07}.$$

So then $x_{48} = (1.07)^{48}(1000) + \dfrac{25\left(1 - 1.07^{48}\right)}{1 - 1.07} = 34560.66$

Thus over $48$ months, or $4$ years, we will have \$$34560.66$ in the account.